# Implement ARToolkit SDK for Augmented reality for iOS application

Tags: ios, artoolkit, augmented-reality

I am actually new to Augmented Reality and I have to make a simple augmented reality app of rendering a 3d object over camera view in iOS (Not with Unity!).

I have downloaded the ARToolKit and checked it by running the sample projects. In the sample project for iOS , there is a pattern/object recognition of an image and a 3d cube model is rendered over it.

My question is - 
How do I change the image that is recognised? How is the pattern recognition code working in it ? 
Secondly , how do I change the Cube (3d model) that is augmented over the camera view ?

Please help! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the [ARToolKit documentation](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/) help?

Comment: Yes! I went through this doc but didn't find anything handy about replacing cube and pattern recognition!